# cmd.exe tab completion character set to something odd

Tags: windows, command-line, sp3, autocomplete

**Background:**

I have an install of Windows XP SP3 OEM that I use often.  Recently its `cmd.exe` somehow forgot that pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> means I want to use the completion feature.

I found out [how to fix this problem](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244407) here, and it worked just fine.

**Cause for concern:**

I was surprised and confused by what the completion character was set to.

The completion character was set to the ASCII `SUB` character, 0x1a, or 26.

**My questions:**

2. What is the ASCII `SUB` character, 0x1a, or 26, used for?  Can I type it?  Can I type it in one keystroke?
3. What could have caused it to be set to anything else that the ASCII `TAB` character, 0x09, or 9?

Comment: Interesting, +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of the Windows command prompt, ASCII 26 represents an [end of file character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Z). You can type it in the command prompt by holding and releasing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> (in that order) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>. It will produce `^Z` (Control-Z). In other applications, you will see a right-facing arrow with the Alt combination, and the Ctrl combination likely performs an undo operation, depending on the software.

I haven't personally seen this behavior, maybe some software you installed had altered it. A very interesting problem though nonetheless!

Comment: What a pain!  Although `Control-Z` is much shorter than `Alt+Fn+K` followed by `Alt+Fn+O` on my laptop, I'll just leave it as `Tab`.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got things sorted out, you're more than welcome :)